# Entity Framework - Dynamic Filters on child/parent entities

Tags: entity-framework

I have a question that I hope someone might be able to help me out with. I'm using Entity Framework 6 with Dynamic Filters to do stuff like filtering out soft deleted entities like so:

```
modelBuilder.Filter("SoftDeleteEntity", (ISoftDeleteEntity d) => d.DateDeleted, null);
```

However - I have a need to filter the entire graph when querying. So let's say that I have:

```
public class Company
{
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }

    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public Company Company { get; set; }
}
```

It's easy for me to filter out the in-active companies by creating a new filter:

```
modelBuilder.Filter("InactiveCompaniesFilter", (Company c) => c.Active, true);
```

However - if I now query my Products then I'll still get all Products belonging to inactive companies. I can of course avoid this be doing this everywhere I query my products:

```
_dbContext.Products.Where(i => i.Company.Active)
```

But as the application grows this becomes a major pain. 
So the question is - can I create an Entity Framework filter that works across child/parent entities?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Is there any reason you couldn’t do modelBuilder.Filter("InactiveCompanyProductsFilter", (Products p) => p.Company.Active, true);

Comment: @S.Walker I thought about it - but the current solution has a lot of entities. So if there was a single global way of doing it that would be preferable.
But I agree - your approach is also doable :)